# RegExp on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, regex, object, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble running this piece of javascript on IE8, it works fine with Firefox but after some research I found out that there's a bug in IE8 with RegExp.

I keep getting **"Object does not support this property or method"** at `var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi")`

How can I modifiy the code to make it work with both IE8 and Firefox 28 and any other browser?

```
function translateDefs(str){  //function to translate digit definitions
  var mapObj = {
          "111-222" : "Primary",
          "333-444" : "Seconday"
          }; 
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");

    return str[1].replace(re, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** I added this polyfill and it worked:

```
if (!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o) {
  if (o !== Object(o))
    throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on a non-object');
  var k=[],p;
  for (p in o) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) k.push(p);
  return k;
}
```

Comment: Try adding the polyfill given in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @Mr_Green I tried that, it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support the [Object.keys](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys) method, try typing `Object.keys({"111-222" : "Primary""333-444" : "Seconday"});` in the IE8 "dev tools console" and see what you get. You could create that function if it does not exist:

```
// From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }

      var result = [], prop, i;

      for (prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          result.push(prop);
        }
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
            result.push(dontEnums[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }());
}


function translateDefs(str){  //function to translate digit definitions
  var mapObj = {
          "111-222" : "Primary",
          "333-444" : "Seconday"
          }; 
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");

    return str[1].replace(re, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't work on IE8, I tried replacing var mapObj ={ .. } to Object.keys({"111-222" : "Primary""333-444" : "Seconday"}); and it stopped working on both browsers.

Comment: what would I change var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi"); to after doing Object.keys({"..."}); ?

Comment: the function Object.keys is not available in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've shimmed Object.keys, the problem is there and not with Regex.  IE8 doesn't support that Object method.

See http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/